# Can't change the div-height vis timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm using [vis.js-timeline](/questions/tagged/vis.js-timeline) and would like div with classes `"vis-panel vis-background vis-vertical"` to be about `600px` high. However, the height (at the moment `198px`) seems to be set programmatically and I haven't  managed to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The user asking the question answered h(im|er)self in a comment earlier; however, it may be useful as an actual answer.

You can do `options = {height: '600px'};` and then in the when you create it, pass in the options. For example:

```
var visObj2d = vis.Timeline(container, dataset, options);
```

I found [this vis documentation](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/#Configuration_Options) to be particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you could try to override the height of the css class.
If you use the jQuery library, you could try to overwrite as follows:

```
var interval = 2000;  // 2 seconds.
var height = "600px"; // New heigth.
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".vis-panel.vis-background.vis-vertical").css({"height": height});
}, interval);
```

Why:

Programmatically, in a certain time you can manipulate the properties of a HTML tag, in this case, a div.

This code adds an attribute "style" to the div tag with class "panel vis-vis vis-background-vertical", after 2 seconds the normal rendering of vis timeline. You can increase or decrease the time as you need.

```
style="height: 600px;"
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't work, but I found that you can customise the height in this the options to configure the Timeline: var options = { height: '600px' }. Thanks again, it'll be useful for some other app.

Comment: Ok, you could share your own solution as final answer to this question. Will be very helpful.

Comment: @user2547297 if you think the answer will be helpful to others you can post an Answer to your own question.